# Google cloud CDN, storage and container engine issue with backend-service

Tags: cdn, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a specific use case that I can not seem to solve.

A typical gcloud setup:

- A K8S cluster
- A gcloud storage bucket
- A gcloud loadbalancer

I managed to get my domain `https://cdn.foobar.com/uploads/` to points to a google storage backend without any issue: I can access files. Its the backend service one that fails.

I would like the `CDN` to act as a cache, when a HTTP request hits it such as `https://cdn.foobar.com/assets/x.jpg`, if it does not have a copy of the asset it should query an other domain `https://foobar.com/assets/x.jpg`.

I understood that this what was load balancers `backend-service` were for. (Right?)

The `backend-service` is pointing to the instance group of the k8s cluster and requires a port. I `guessed` that I needed to allow the firewall to expose the `Nodeport` of my web application service for the loadbalancer to be able to query it.

### Cloud CDN

[image]

[image]

### Load balancing

Failing health-checks.

[image]

The backend service is pointing to the instance group of the k8s cluster and requires some ports (default 80?) 80 failed. I `guessed` that I needed to allow the firewall to expose the 32231 `Nodeport` of my web application service for the loadbalancer to be able to query it. That still failed with a 502.

`?> kubectl describe svc
Name:           backoffice-service
Namespace:      default
Labels:         app=backoffice
Selector:       app=backoffice
Type:           NodePort
IP:             10.7.xxx.xxx
Port:           http    80/TCP
NodePort:       http    32231/TCP
Endpoints:      10.4.x.x:8500,10.4.x.x:8500
Session Affinity:   None
No events.`

[image]

I ran out of ideas at this point.
Any hints int the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to confirm the health check endpoint point it's using you can try one of 2 ways:

Through the cloud console: compute > health checks > lookup your health check. It takes the form k8s-be-nodePort-hash, where nodePort in the your case is  32231, as shown by the kubectl output.
Through gcloud: Run gcloud compute http-health-checks list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying your service as type '[NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types)', you are exposing the service on each Node's IP, but the service is not reachable to the exterior, so you need to expose your service as 'LoadBalancer'

Since you're looking to use an HTTP(s) Load Balancer, I'll recommend using a Kubernetes [Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress). This resource will be in charge of configuring the HTTP(s) load balancer and the required ports that your service is using, as well as the health checks on the specified port.

Since you're securing your application, you will need to configure a [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) object for [securing the Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls).

This [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/multi-tls/multi-tls.yaml) will help you getting started on an Ingress with TLS termination.

Comment: Adding a [backend bucket](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing#creating_a_backend_bucket_for_your_cloud_storage_bucket) to your Ingress resource is not possible at the moment. There's this [feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/issues/353) on the Kubernetes Github forum, you can follow up for updates on this matter.